# Electrostatic equilibrium by induced electric field for pure wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

[image]

I have question about the condition that there is no net motion of charge within a conductor(electrostatic equilibrium)

All conductor can't reach to electrostatic equilibrium state

For example, there is a pure wire loop and there is varying magnetic field.

By varying magnetic field(it is linear, fexample B=-B0tz(B0 is a constant,t is time and z is unit vector), there is induced electric field along a wire. In this situation electric field makes positive charges move in CCW and negative charges move in CW. But this will last when varying magnetic field is applied,in other words, induced electric field is produced.

Anyway, it means all conductor can't reach electrostatic equilibrium.

Then what is condition for electrostatic equilibrium??

I think my question is odd,abnormal,foolish but i'm curious abour it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the presence of a varying magnetic field one can not reach electrostatic equilibrium. since it is not "static"

Comment: What if we were to break the metal wire with pliers and create an open circuit, so that the current no longer flows and an electrostatic equilibrium is established?